# Pull entire row based on MAX(Column) MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to pull whole record from database for the highest "Score" column.

TestTable structure

```
------------------
ID | Name | Score|
------------------
1  | john | 10
2  | mark | 20
3  | ted  | 15
```

So when I run

```
SELECT ID, Name, MAX(Score)
FROM TestTable
```

So I want the query to return entire row 2 because this is the highest value.

This is what I am expecting:

```
2  | mark | 20
```

But it does not necessarily return correct row. It always return MAX(Score) but other values are not necessarily from the same row.

This is what I am getting:

```
3  | ted  | 20
```

Is there a better way of pulling this data?
I am using MySQL.

Also I am not interested in sub-query such as

```
SELECT ID, Name, MAX(Score)
FROM TestTable
WHERE ID = (
    SELECT ID From TestTable WHERE Score = MAX(Score);
)
```

Because I need it for big query using a lot of data, and it needs to perform good.

Please help :)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about ties and want one row only and always one row, then the following could be used. With an index on `(Score)`, should be as efficient as possible:

```
SELECT ID, Name, Score
FROM TestTable
ORDER BY Score DESC 
LIMIT 1 ;
```

If you care about ties but still want only one row, you'll have to decide how ties should be resolved and modify the `ORDER BY` accordingly. If, for example, the row with the first `name` in lexicographic order is wanted in case of ties, then use the following - and an index on `(Score, Name)`:

```
ORDER BY Score DESC, Name ASC
```

If you want all tied results, then the query by @Dan in the other answer should be the best. The index on `(Score)` would be sufficient for that.

Comment: Hi, I forgot to add that I need a record per user. I have updated my question

Comment: That changes the question entirely. I suggest you post a new one. Or search the site, there are many similar ones.

Comment: Thank you I have posted new question http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/127055/pull-entire-row-per-user-based-on-maxcolumn-mysql

Answer (score 1):

I only have a SQL Server instance available to me, but I believe this syntax will work for MySQL as well.

```
select  tt.ID
        , tt.Name
        , tt.Score
from TestTable tt
INNER JOIN (select MAX(Score) as MaxScore from TestTable) tt2
ON tt.Score = tt2.MaxScore
```

Using the above, you grab the top score in an inline view, and then inner join against that, causing only records with a `Score` value equal to `MaxScore` to be returned.

Given your example, this will return the top score. **Note**, if more than 1 record shares the top score, you'll get multiple records back which share that score.

Comment: Hi, I forgot to add that I need a record per user. I have updated my question